# Attempting to link GA4 Audiences to SFMC Journey Builder as an Entry Source

Tags: google-analytics, salesforce, google-analytics-4, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am working on a project where I have come across an issue with connecting Audiences from GA4 to SFMC so I can use them in Journey Builder.

Currently my GA4 is properly linked to SFMC as we are pulling data but unfortunately the steps to complete setting up a link for Audiences is not possible. We are unable to complete step number 3 in this doc [https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9250031](https://stackoverflow.com). SFMC does not appear under the Product Links section and there doesn't seem to be a way for me to add it or search for more. [Image of what I see on Analytics for the Property Link section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUJG0.png). I do have editing access just as an FYI.
I saw that this is possibly an outdated solution, although it is still the recommended solution both from GA and SFMC, so I attempted to find a solution in the GA4 property docs but can only find solutions to connecting audiences to other google marketing products [https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12800258?hl=en&ref_topic=9303474&sjid=13275861648971256031-EU.](https://stackoverflow.com)
The only other solution I found on stack overflow appears outdated as its from 2019 [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278254/google-analytics-audience-not-available-in-journey-builder.](https://stackoverflow.com) 
I know there was a recent update with GA4 but the docs don't seem to cover this as far as I can find. Has anyone come across this problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I contacted SF support and got this response:

> I looked at your settings and it appears that you have GA4 integrated rather than GA360. In that case GA4 is currently not supported with the product link - you would only see this product link with a GA 360 account type. When it will be supported, the linking and configuration process will be different and the help docs will be updated at that time.
> I also spoke with our product team and they advised that you will need to have the conversions tied to the Journey within Google Analytics itself rather than Marketing Cloud. Marketing Cloud is only making an API call to GA to retrieve that data and if that configuration is not set up in GA then Marketing Cloud will not be able to grab that data. As we do not have access to the GA configurations I have been advised that this will need to be addressed with Google Analytics directly.

Hope that helps.